# How do I match similar names to a given row if they appear in one year and not the next and appear again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matching, data-cleaning

Actual Question (couldn't add to title because it's too long): I have facility names in a list of list, where each list is for a corresponding year. I want to create a data frame, with each row containing a unique facility name. The problem is, some years a facility name might appear, and in the next year, it could be absent and in the following year, it could appear again and so forth. Also there are facilities that don't appear until much later. I've been trying to create a data frame that matches unique facility names to a row (where they first appear) but I've been unsuccessful.

Ideal:

```py
Headers  = ['1999','2000','2001','2002','2003']
file1999 = ['Factory_A']
file2000 = ['Factory_A','Factory_B']
file2001 = ['Factory_B']
file2002 = ['Factory_A','Factory_C']
file2003 = ['Factory_A','Factory_B','Factory_C']

1999          2000           2001       2002       2003

Factory_A     Factory_A      NA         Factory_A  Factory_A

NA            Factory_B      Factory_B  NA         Factory_B

NA            NA             NA         Factory_C  Factory_C
```

I thought I could just merge the the lists using a loop, but this didn't garner the result I need.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Factories':['NaN']})
for i, j in zip((files), (Headers)):
    new_DF = pd.DataFrame({'Factories':i})
    df = df.merge(new_DF, on = ['Factories'],how='right')

# I got this with 'right'
    Factories
0   Factory_A
1   Factory_C
2   Factory_B

# I then tried to append a new column

df = pd.DataFrame({'Factories':['NaN']})
for i, j in zip(files, Headers):
    new_DF = pd.DataFrame({'Factories':i})
    df[j] = new_DF

# But I got this result instead:
    Factories   1999    2000    2001    2002    2003
0   NaN     Factory_A   Factory_A   Factory_B   Factory_A   Factory_A
```

Comment: Can you please share your expected output? It will give a better insight to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following solution:

```
from itertools import chain

lists = [file1999, file2000, file2001, file2002, file2003]
names = sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(lists)))
sets = map(set, lists)
dct = {col: [name if name in s else pd.np.nan for name in names] for col, s in zip(Headers, sets)}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        1999       2000       2001       2002       2003
0  Factory_A  Factory_A        NaN  Factory_A  Factory_A
1        NaN  Factory_B  Factory_B        NaN  Factory_B
2        NaN        NaN        NaN  Factory_C  Factory_C
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first build a list of the `fileyyyy` lists:

```
files = [file1999, file2000, file2001, file2002, file2003]
```

It is then simple:

```
words = sorted(set.union(*[set(file) for file in files]))

df = pd.DataFrame({k:
                   [word if (word in files[i]) else 'NA' for word in words]
                   for i, k in enumerate(Headers)})
```

You get:

```
1999       2000       2001       2002       2003
Factory_A  Factory_A         NA  Factory_A  Factory_A
       NA  Factory_B  Factory_B         NA  Factory_B
       NA         NA         NA  Factory_C  Factory_C
```